# Getting the version of an installed package sometime return no result on alpine

Tags: alpine-linux

In Linux Alpine I use `apk version package` to retrieve the installed version of a package. For some reason, some packages simply does not return any result. Is there another way to do that or am I missing something?

```
docker run -it --rm alpine:3.15
apk add bash openssh-client

# Installs packages

apk version bash
Installed:                                Available:
bash-5.1.8-r0                           = 5.1.8-r0

apk version openssh-client
Installed:                                Available:
```

Answer (score 2):

If all that is required is human readable version info, that is still obtainable from apk for openssh-client using:

```
~ # apk info openssh-client
openssh-client-default-9.3_p1-r3 description:
OpenBSD's SSH client

openssh-client-default-9.3_p1-r3 webpage:
https://www.openssh.com/portable.html
...
```

As to `apk version`, firstly `apk version any_unrecognised_string` returns exactly the same empty output.  I think this is because openssh-client is a meta package, a collection of other packages bundled for convenience.  Like build-base, but unlike build-base perhaps all openssh-client's metadata hasn't yet been provided by the uploader.

`apk add openssh-client` installs 3 applications (and perhaps more).  This can be seen by doing:

```
~ # apk info | grep openssh*
openssh-client-common
openssh-client-default
openssh-keygen
```

Version info for each of those programs can be looked up using its full name, e.g. `apk version openssh-client-common`.  Or for all three by:

```
~ # apk info | grep openssh* | xargs apk version
Installed:                                Available:
openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3         = 9.3_p1-r3
openssh-client-default-9.3_p1-r3        = 9.3_p1-r3
openssh-keygen-9.3_p1-r3                = 9.3_p1-r3
```

Comment: A little late to the party, but that makes sense! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome.  I couldn't even find a listing for openssh-client on the package index's website, so there's defintiely something different about it.  https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openssh-client&branch=edge&repo=&arch=&maintainer=